# SSH Server randomly stops accepting connections

Tags: ssh

I have setup an ssh server on a computer at my workplace so I can work remotly, and it is mostly working great.

But from time to time (about once every other week), the ssh connection suddenly stops while I am using it. When that happens, the server will never accept any ssh connection again, until I reboot it manually.

edit: To be more precise, it doesn't "reject" the connection, it just stays stuck forever

I am sure there must be some workarounds for a situation like this, so I don't have to be physically in front of my computer every time something like this happens. Do you have any advice about this?

Here's the verbose output when the ssh connection fails:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/hedi/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/hedi/.ssh/config line 6: Applying options for inubushiPC
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 133.11.35.15 [133.11.35.15] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/hedi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
```

Comment: SSH should be (and looks to be here) rock solid. They key is that it can't access the files it needs in your home directory.  I wonder if /home is a network share (eg NFS) and if its getting locked up on a network event and not recovering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symptoms are very similar to when a Linux VPS runs out of memory with swap turned off. Usually it's due to some process consumes too much memory, to the point the system can't provide any more, but the process doesn't crash, just gets stuck. Any new SSH connection (or even other TCP connections) needs some memory to initialize, but there is not enough  left and the initialization simply never completes (I don't know the in-depth reason for this though).

You may be able to confirm the actual condition when it happens to your machine with some monitoring solution. The simplest way might be *atop*, which can record the machine's state (CPU/RAM usage by procs...) regularly and write it to a file. You can consult this file after the next reboot to be sure that the cause is out of memory, and also which processes were using too much of it. The downside is generally you can only access the log on the machine, i.e. you can only analyse it *after* the machine fails and you (manually) reboot it. You may couple it with some logging solution that sends logs to other machine, but that's a lot more involved.

The solution for actually preventing such failure is less clear-cut:

- After you determine the process that was causing out-of-memory, you may restrict its resource usage so it won't consume all of memory again. The details on doing that may depend on the actual process / application, and is worth expanding on another question (though you may find a lot of generic guides for that).
- Turning swap on (also, plenty of guides for that) is another options, though I couldn't ascertain its effectiveness.
- Another approach, as well as a last resort, is [https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/fallback-reboot/](https://stromberg.dnsalias.org/%7Estrombrg/fallback-reboot/), an utility that purportedly allows you to remotely reboot the machine when you find no other way to access it. *Disclaimer: I have never actually used it before, and I'm not affiliated with the utility in any way, only heard some good things about it. Use at your own risk!*

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try your solutions and hope it solves the issue!